# How to add more content below a MpAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have a PieChart that is working perfectly. However, I need to have more content - EditText, Texviews, and Buttons, below the PieChart. I want the users to be able to scroll down and see different content.
I have a RelativeLayout inside of a LinearLayout whose orientation is vertical but nothing shows.

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                    android:id="@+id/pie_chart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Click me"
            />

     </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `LinearLayout` under `ScrollView`. It should work.

In your chart, make height to `wrap_content`.

It should look something like this:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
            android:id="@+id/pie_chart"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Click me"
    />

    </LinearLayout>    

</ScrollView>
```